# Putting Rails code into jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use a jQuery function to put a partial into my code. The jQuery is pretty simple, but how can I input Rails code so I don't have to write the html from scratch?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function addCommentBoxToID(myID)
{
    $('#post' + myID + ' .postcontent tbody').append('I want to put rails code here');
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would not be the way to do it. You cannot include a partial in your code true jQuery.

jQuery is clientside, Ruby on Rails code is executed on the server. You cannot execute Rails code true jQuery.

Closest to what you want including html content generated by rails would be using some ajax to call you rails app and give a command to spit out a piece of HTML. Look into rails and ajax on railscasts.com to get a basic idea.

Comment: this is one of the best features of Rails, it makes the ajax request very easy for you. All you have to do is an ajax request, then on the server side just return a partial containing the post html.

Comment: I'm actually already using ajax to insert each post, but I think you're right and I'm going to have to reorganize the way my code works.

Answer (score 2):

app/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
.... (the fields for the comment)
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
def create
  @article = Article.find params[:article_id]
  @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      (other formats)
      format.js
    end
  else
    render 'articles/show'
  end
end
```

app/views/comments/create.js.erb

```
$('#post' + myID + ' .postcontent tbody').append('<%=j render @comment %>')
```

or if you want to put the content of the variable:

```
$('#post' + myID + ' .postcontent tbody').append('<%=j @comment.content %>')
```

app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
  (your partial)
```

Don't forget to escape javascript:

```
<%=j ... %> or (a bit longer) <%=escape_javascript ...%>
```

Otherwise it will be a complete mess with the quotes/double-quotes etc.

Answer (score 2):

Normally JavaScript works in the client side, but it's is also possible that your application draws a javaScript function for a each client. In that case you can use the `<%=` and tags `%>` in a .erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    new AClass.function({
        text: <%= Date.today %>
    });
});
</script>
```